# Программа поиска произведения последовательности чисел

Tags: java

> Написать программу поиска произведения последовательности чисел, вводимых с клавиатуры, предшествующих первому введенному отрицательному числу. Должен многократно выполняться оператор ввода LineNumberReader. Пример: 1,2,3, 4,5,-2. Результат: 120

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     LineNumberReader lnReader = 
         new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     ArrayList buffer = new ArrayList();
     int k = 1;
     int sum = 1;
     try {
         k = Integer.valueOf(lnReader.readLine());
         while (k > 0) {
             buffer.add(k);
             k = Integer.valueOf(lnReader.readLine());
         }
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         System.err.println("Это не число");
     } catch (IOException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
     }

     k = 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++)
         k *= (Integer) buffer.get(i);
     System.out.println(k);
 }
```

Правильно ли?

Comment: А зачем ArrayList buffer? Можно накапливать произведение. Если оставить список-массив, то лучше задать тип ArrayList: `ArrayList<Integer> buffer = new ArrayList<Integer>();` (тогда лишним станет приведение типа в строке `k*=(Integer)buffer.get(i);`

Answer (score 1):

Несколько комментариев к коду:

1. Это как раз тот случай когда цикл должен быть пост-условный, то есть с проверкой в конце выполнения, а не перед как у вас. То есть конструкция: `do {} while`, а не `while {}`
2. Зачем копить значения в массив? Лучше их сразу умножать и держать результат - как и подсказывал @alexiz
3. При ловле экспешена - надо по идее опять возвращать к чтению строки